# Impact by reflected xss with httpOnly cookies

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, xss, cookie-httponly

I found reflected xss and am trying to use cookies with the httpOnly flag.  I know that httpOnly doesn't allow you to access cookies via JavaScript, but is there really no way to do this (I know about the Trace request, but this is not an option in my case)?  And how else can I use reflected xss if can't read cookies with httpOnly?

Comment: You don't need to read the cookie values. Just make the injected code execute the requests that you want to make, the cookies will be included on them.

Comment: How can I make request via js if for request succeed I need verifications cookies like a CSRF token and so on? But I can't access to verification cookies via js cause it's httpOnly and verification cookies don't added automatically to my request. My request just blocked by website's server because it's don't approved by server

Comment: Httponly cookies are still cookies and *do* get automatically added to the requests sent from the victim's browser to the server during an active session. That's how it works for "normal" requests that are made by the intended (non-xss) js code on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access HttpOnly cookies from JavaScript and the TRACE header is not that commonly supported in the backends.

However, there are many other attacks that a hacker can execute through XSS, like redirecting the user, changing content/links on the pages, and extracting data from the page.

Comment: Can I just parse (using js libraries) the cookies with httpOnly?

Comment: No, you can't access them from JavaScript and that is the whole point with HttpOnly. For example, there is no need for JavaScript to access sensitive session cookies for example.